# mysql syntax error from rails app but works from mysql console

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, insert, explain

While using the following rails mechanism form their official guide at http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/classes/ActiveSupport/LogSubscriber.html, the following query logs an error when executed from the rails application

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `encrypted`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_typ' at line 1: EXPLAIN INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `encrypted`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `object_changes`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2014-03-19 04:31:21', 1, 'Patient Load', 0, 'Query', 'ncevON0nZrNtrvn2oiQVmjjolF4E7K4/hk7QC3bCwFRvPnyU5HL348IJiIjw\nYs8f\n', 'ncevON0nZrNtrvn2oiQVmjjolF4E7K4/hk7QC3bCwFRvPnyU5HL348IJiIjw\nYs8f\n', 1)
```

but when run from mysql console, it works perfectly.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `versions` (`created_at`, `encrypted`, `event`, `item_id`, `item_type`, `object`, `object_changes`, `whodunnit`) VALUES ('2014-03-19 04:31:21', 1, 'Patient Load', 0, 'Query', 'ncevON0nZrNtrvn2oiQVmjjolF4E7K4/hk7QC3bCwFRvPnyU5HL348IJiIjw\nYs8f\n', 'ncevON0nZrNtrvn2oiQVmjjolF4E7K4/hk7QC3bCwFRvPnyU5HL348IJiIjw\nYs8f\n', 1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

My code looks like...

```
class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber
  def sql(event)
    if [:accounts, :users].any? {|e| event.payload[:sql] =~ /^SELECT(.+)#{e}/}
      begin
        Version.create( item_type: 'Query', item_id: 0, event: (event.payload[:name] || event.payload[:sql].split(' ').first || 'Unknown'), whodunnit: User.current.try(:id), object: event.payload[:sql], object_changes: event.payload[:sql])
      rescue 
      end
    end
  end
end

LogSubscriber.attach_to :active_record unless Rails.env.test?
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute an `EXPLAIN` on your `INSERT ..` statement?

Comment: Maybe because you are using "object" which would describe Object, a predefined class in ruby. I had the same when I used "type" as field name, I had to rename it.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis: So long as the names are back ticked, they are acceptable. Error seems not with it, but at or before the `INSERT` word.

Comment: @ramonrails: Can you please post your rails script code used to generated the SQL command.

Comment: @StavrosSouvatzis: "Type" is special field name in rails used for Single Table Inheritance. It is not related in any way to this error. "object" is a valid mysql field name and the SQL is working correct from mysql console. "object" is also not confused by rails with the Object class and verified by me in the code too.

Comment: @Ravinder I am using the rails logging mechanism http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/classes/ActiveSupport/LogSubscriber.html to log certain events.

Comment: @ramonrails: How is the content on that page directly related to your issue?

Comment: @Ravinder Please see the updated description of this question.